# Why rsync doesn't work as a schedule cron task?

Tags: 18.04, cron, rsync

I am running this command from terminal and it works well. Files ares uploaded to the remote server without having to type any password.

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" --delete /home/me/backup/bin/backup/bio root@vpsxxxxxx.ovh.net:backups_bio/ --log-file=$HOME/rsync.log
```

But if I run it from crontab I am getting this error :

> 2019/08/08 16:04:02 [3062] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0
>   bytes received so far) [sender] 2019/08/08 16:04:02 [3062] rsync
>   error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]

And the upload doesn't work.
Why doesn't it work when launched from Crontab?
I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: `/home/.ssh/` and `/home/backup` are the real folders? Might be `$HOME` is not set for cron ?! You should try to use absolute paths. Also, put  `--log-file=` in front as it's part of `[OPTION...]`.

Comment: yes, they are the real folders. The log file works fine, I don't have any problem with $HOME.

Comment: and the folder `/home/.ssh` belongs to which user? How did you add the cronjob? (I'm asking, because people tend to use `root` cronjobs when they should use user cronjobs...)

Comment: I m creating the cron entry by typing "crontab -e", and it looks like "58 16 * * * rsync ....."    The .ssh doesn't belong to root user but to a standard user which I use to log in the ubuntu server

Comment: "rsync" use absolute paths. "--log-file=$HOME/rsync.log" That is not going to work. "/home/.ssh/" what is that? You do NOT add files to /home/ yourself. Use something like /usr/local/ if you need it globally. "/home/backup/" only correct if you have a user nackup. Otherwise... no

Comment: $HOME/rsync.log works as I actually can read the rsync.log file in $HOME directory.  /home/.ssh is where ssh keys are stored when I create them. I didnt' create it myself, SSH did choose the folder itself.

Comment: `ssh-keygen` would choose `/home/user/.ssh`.

Comment: my fault, in my post, I didn't put the right path (i updated it). The weird thing is that the script works fine when ran manually.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing the *private* identity file to SSH i.e. `ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa` (not `id_rsa.pub`)? FYI `$HOME` is fine; it's part of the (reduced) cron environment as described here [Set environment variable UBUNTU 18.04 (bionic) - Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/1059384/178692) and will be expanded into an absolute path by the shell in which the job is run (`/bin/sh`, by default)

Comment: steeldriver, it works. Why do I need private identity file in a cron job whereas I can run the script manually with the public identity file? Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: @thomas tbh I don't know why it would have worked with the "wrong" file from the command line - possibly because your desktop session is running an ssh agent that has already cached the identity?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here as an ssh newbie, but couldn't it simply be that ssh-keygen was run as a regular user (so it works from the command line), but the cron job runs as root so the generated key won't work?